# ACR - delete only old images - variable reference not vald

Tags: azure, azure-container-registry

Im trying to cleanup old images in my ACR. It has 8 repositories so first I want it to test it in only one of them... The complicated thing about it that I need to keep last 4 images created. So I have this script:

```
$acrName = ACRttestt

$repo = az acr repository list --name $acrName --top 1

$repo | Convertfrom-json | Foreach-Object {
    $imageName = $_
    (az acr repository show-tags -n $acrName --repository $_ | 
       convertfrom-json |) Select-Object -SkipLast 4 | Foreach-Object {
           az acr repository delete -n $acrName --image "$imageName:$_"
       }
}
```

But Im receiving the following error:

> Failed At line:9 char:58 + ... az acr repository delete -n $acrName
>   --image "$imageName:$_" + ~~~~~~~~~~~ Variable reference is not valid. ':' was not followed by a valid variable name character. Consider
>   using ${} to delimit the name.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the `"$imageName:$_"` into `"${imageName}:$_"`. Then the script will like below:

```
$acrName = "ACRttestt"

$repo = az acr repository list --name $acrName --top 1

$repo | Convertfrom-json | Foreach-Object {
    $imageName = $_
    (az acr repository show-tags -n $acrName --repository $_ | 
       convertfrom-json |) Select-Object -SkipLast 4 | Foreach-Object {
           az acr repository delete -n $acrName --image "${imageName}:$_"
       }
}
```